# Intel RST Drive missing error -- with a twist

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8.1, motherboard, raid, intel-rst

I'm beginning to think that Intel RST software on Windows 8.1 is having issues.

### The Components Involved

I am using the following:

- Windows 8.1
- Asus Maximus V Extreme motherboard with latest firmware & drivers from the manufacturer
- Intel RST 12.8.0.1016 (latest version available on manufacturer web site)
- 2x2TB Seagate hard drives (previously, 1x1TB Western Digital hard drives)

### What happens

- I see a warning in my system tray that my RAID is degraded
- I see the following screen in Intel RST:

[image]

### Why This is Bizarre

- I saw this problem on Windows 8.1 last time, so I found the drive in question and replaced it.
- The issue happened again, so I thought it might be the cable and replaced it.
- The issue continued happening, so I thought it must be an issue with the disk controller on the motherboard, so I **replaced the entire motherboard**

Now, with brand new disks and brand new cables on a brand new motherboard and a new OS set up from scratch and the manufacturer-recommended versions of software, this problem still plagues me.

### Question

Does anybody know how to stop Intel RST from thinking that one of my (perfectly good new) drives on my (perfectly good new) motherboard with (perfectly good new) cables has just up and disappeared?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, the issue was one of assumptions (d'oh!) and similar symptoms.

While previously I believe the motherboard was bad, in this case some unexpected pressure on a cable seems to have repeatedly made it slightly loose. It lost contact at one point which is what caused the reset and degradation.

So it was the same symptom but a different cause entirely.

Up and running with legitimate RAID and very happy about it.

Comment: Feel free to accept your own answer. Without an accepted answer 'community' will occasionally bump it to the front page.